# SharePoint 2010 User Profile Sync - Remove Disabled Users

Tags: user-profile, profile-sync

I have SharePoint 2010 set up to sync active directory users and it is working great. I am getting disabled users in the sync though. I have tried what all the blogs say, filter on

userAccountControl bit on equals 2

but to no avail, the disabled users are still syncing. I am at a loss on where to look next. My last resort would be to create a ou/folder in AD and move disabled users there and remove that from the sync connector, but I don't really want to go there.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The link below describes how to remove disabled users.

http://www.bryanporter.com/archive/2010/02/20/excluding-disabled-user-accounts-from-profile-synchronization-in-sharepoint-2010.aspx

Comment: This link leads to a 404...someone have an updated link, or able to put the actual content into an answer?

Comment: Please add the answer here... Do Not post only a link.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any other exclusion filters on that same connection?  If so, then it is possible that you accidentally added one of them using **OR** instead of **AND**.  Unfortunately if you look at the filters after they were applied it will not tell you whether they were created using AND or OR.  The only thing to do would be to delete the filters and re-add them while making sure that you correctly have AND or OR selected when you add them.